# Ionic infinite scroll with dribbble pagination data?

Tags: angularjs, ajax, dribbble-api

I am messing around with ionic and am using dribbble data just to play around. I am not sure how A. I can query dribble to show posts beyond the first 15, the api is here http://api.dribbble.com/shots/everyone and if I want to get more I can request page 2 like http://api.dribbble.com/shots/everyone?page=2

B. How do I pass the items into my template without conflicting with the old items?

```
/**
 * Dashboard Controller. (must be authenticated)
 *
 */
.controller('DashController', function($scope, $state, DribbbleData, $http) {

  $scope.items = [];

  $scope.initialize = function() {
    DribbbleData.getData().then(function(res) {
      console.log(res);
      $scope.items = res.data.shots;
    }, function(status) {
      console.log('error')
    })
  }

  $scope.loadMore = function() {
    $http.jsonp('http://api.dribbble.com/shots/everyone?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(items) {
      console.log(items);
      var test = $scope.items;
      console.log(test)
      //$scope.items = items;
      //useItems(items);
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
    });
  };

  $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
    $scope.loadMore();
  });

  $scope.initialize();
})
```

The View

```
<ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
  <ion-content class="padding">

    <ion-list>
      <div class="list card" data-ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div class="item item-title">
          <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="item item-body">
          <img class="full-image" ng-src="{{item.image_url}}">
          <p>
            <a href="#" class="subdued">{{item.likes_count}} Like</a>
            <a href="#" class="subdued">{{item.comments_count}} Comments</a>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="item tabs tabs-secondary tabs-icon-left">
          <a class="tab-item" href="#">
            <i class="icon ion-thumbsup"></i>
            Like
          </a>
          <a class="tab-item" href="#">
            <i class="icon ion-chatbox"></i>
            Comment
          </a>
          <a class="tab-item" href="#">
            <i class="icon ion-share"></i>
            Share
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-infinite-scroll on-infinite="loadMore()" distance="1%">
    </ion-infinite-scroll>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: You want to append the new items at the bottom of your list right ?

Comment: Yeah but the main issue is making a request to retrieve page 2 then page 3

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand you perfectly. You mean you are having trouble generating the correct URL?

Comment: No sorry to be confusing but the dribble api only returns 15 items. To get the next 15 you have to request page 2 or 3 or 4 http://api.dribbble.com/shots/everyone?page=3. So inside the infinite scrolling I have to detect the value of what the request amount is, example the first infinite request does a request to http://api.dribbble.com/shots/everyone?page=2 then on the second iteration request http://api.dribbble.com/shots/everyone?page=3 then http://api.dribbble.com/shots/everyone?page=4

Comment: I updated my answer. Does this answers your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sure that there are no duplicates, just concat the items:

```
$scope.items = $scope.items.concat(items);
```

if you are not, the best thing to do is keep track of the items currently in your list, and add only when it does not exist yet:

```
var itemIds = {};

function addItems(items) {
  items.forEach(function (item) {
    if (itemsIds[item.id]) {
      return;
    }
    $scope.items.push(item);
    itemIds[item.id] = true;
  }
}
```

To handle pagination, just increment a counter in your success callback. For example:

```
  var nextPage = 2;

  $scope.loadMore = function() {
    $http.jsonp('http://api.dribbble.com/shots/everyone?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&page=' + nextPage).success(function(items) {
      nextPage++;
      addItems(items);
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
    });
  };
```

Comment: How can I do this in an Ionic 3 way?

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to add the new items to your `$scope.items` array when the ajax completes

```
  $scope.loadMore = function() {
    $http.jsonp('http://api.dribbble.com/shots/everyone?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(items) {
      // Add all the new items
      items.forEach(function(newItem) {
        $scope.items.push(newItem);
      });
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
    });
  };
```